# OpenGL what do I have to do before drawing a triangle?

Tags: c++, opengl

Most of the tutorials, guides and books that I've found out there are related to OpenGL, explains how to draw a triangle and initialize OpenGL. That's fine. But when they try to explain it they just list a bunch of functions and parameters like:

```
glClear()
glClearColor()
glBegin()
glEnd()
...
```

Since I'm not very good at learning things by memory, I always need an answer to "why are we doing this?" so that I'll write that bunch of functions because I remember that I have to set a certain things before doing somethings else and so on not because the tutorial told me so.

Could please someone explain to me what do I have to define to OpenGL (only pure OpenGL, I'm using SFML as background library but that really doesn't matter) before starting to draw something with `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`?

Sample answer:

> You have to first tell OpenGL what color does it need to clear the
>   screen with. Because each frame needs to be cleared by the previous
>   before we start to draw the current one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you should know, that OpenGL is a state machine. That means, that apart from creating the OpenGL context (which is done by SFML) there's no such thing as initialization!

> Since I'm not very good at learning things by memory,

This is good…

> I always need an answer to "why are we doing this?"

This is excellent!

> Could please someone explain to me what do I have to define to OpenGL (only pure OpenGL, I'm using SFML as background library but that really doesn't matter) before starting to draw something with glBegin() and glEnd()?

As I already told: OpenGL is a state machine. That basically means, that there are two kinds of calls you can do: Setting state and executing operations.

For example `glClearColor` sets a state variable, that of the clear color, which value is used for clearing the active framebuffer color to, when a call to `glClear` with the `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` flag set. There exists a similar function `glClearDepth` for the depth value (`GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` flag to `glClear`).

`glBegin` and `glEnd` belong to the immediate mode of OpenGL, which have been deprecated. So there's little reason in learning them. You should use Vertex Arrays instead, preferrably through Vertex Buffer Objects.

But here it goes: `glBegin` sets OpenGL in a state that it should now draw geometry, of the kind of primitive selected as parameter to `glBegin`. `GL_TRIANGLES` for example means, that OpenGL will now interpret every 3 calls to `glVertex` as forming a triangle. `glEnd` tells OpenGL that you've finished *that* batch of triangles. Within a glBegin…glEnd block certain state changes are disallowed. Among those everything that has to do with transforming the geometry and generating the picture, which matrices, shaders, textures, and some others.

One common misconception is, that OpenGL is initialized. This is due to badly written tutorials which have a `initGL` function or similar. It's a good practice to set all state from scratch when beginning to render a scene. But since a single frame may contain several scenes (think of a HUD or split screen gaming) this happens several times a scene.

---

#### Update:

So how do you draw a triangle? Well, it's simple enough. First you need the geometry data. For example this:

```
GLfloat triangle[] = {
    -1, 0, 0,
    +1, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 0
};
```

In the render function we tell OpenGL that the next calls to glDrawArrays or glDrawElements shall fetch the data from there (for the sake of simplicity I'll use OpenGL-2 functions here):

```
glVertexPointer(3, /* there are three scalars per vertex element */
                GL_FLOAT, /* element scalars are float */
                0, /* elements are tightly packed (could as well be sizeof(GLfloat)*3 */
                trignale /* and there you find the data */ );
/* Note that glVertexPointer does not make a copy of the data! 
   If using a VBO the data is copied when calling glBufferData. */

/* this switches OpenGL into a state that it will
   actually access data at the place we pointed it
   to with glVertexPointer */
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

/* glDrawArrays takes data from the supplied arrays and draws them
   as if they were submitted sequentially in a for loop to immediate
   mode functions. Has some valid applications. Better use index
   based drawing for models with a lot of shared vertices. */
glDrawArrays(Gl_TRIANGLE, /* draw triangles */
             0, /* start at index 0 */
             3, /* process 3 elements (of 3 scalars each) */ );
```

What I didn't include yet is setting up the transformation and viewport mapping.

The viewport defines how the readily projected and normalized geometry is placed in the window. This state is set using `glViewport(pos_left, pos_bottom, width, height)`.

Transformation today happens in a vertex shader, Essentially a vertex shader is a small program written in a special language (GLSL), that takes the vertex attributes and calculates the clip space position of the resulting vertex. The usual approach for this is emulating the fixed function pipeline, which is a two stage process: First transform the geometry into view space (some calculations, like illumination are easier in this space), then project it into clip space, which is kind of the lens of the renderer. In the fixed function pipeline there are two transformation matrices for this: Modelview and Projection. You set them to whatever is required for the desired outcome. In the case of just a triangle, we leave the modelview identity and use a ortho projection from -1 to 1 in either dimension.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
/* the following function multiplies onto what's already on the stack,
   so reset it to identity */
glLoadIdentity(); 

/* our clip volume is defined by 6 orthogonal planes with normals X,Y,Z
   and ditance 1 from origin into each direction */
glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1); 

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
/* now a identity matrix is loaded onto the modelview */
glLoadIdentity();
```

Having set up the transformation we can now draw the triangle as outlined above:

```
draw_triangle();
```

Finally we need to tell OpenGL we're done with sending commands and it should finish it's renderings.

```
if(singlebuffered)
    glFinish();
```

However most of the time your window is double buffered, so you need to swap it to make things visime. Since swapping makes no sense without finishing the swap implies a finish

```
else
    SwapBuffers();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Then every OpenGL function should be used in each frame (so put in the main loop) right because there's no OpenGL initialization functions, right?

Comment: A mention of glBegin/glEnd being deprecated would be nice.

Comment: @Cubic: Eh, pleae reread my answer again. It's right there: "glBegin and glEnd belong to the immediate mode of OpenGL, **which have been deprecated.**"

Comment: @Jeffrey: Well not *every* OpenGL function. But everything that is relevant to get the desired outcome, which means setting all the required state, and more importantly making sure no interfering states from previous OpenGL calls mess up your drawing. Up to including OpenGL-2.1 this was a quite a tedious job. Now with OpenGL-3 core profile, which deprecated a lot of the annoying stuff, state space has been reduced to a much smaller, manageable dimensionality.

Comment: @datenwolf Yeah sorry, somehow missed that line.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the API to set and change the OpenGL state machine.

You're not actually programming directly to the GPU, you're using a medium between your application and your GPU to do whatever you're trying to do.

The reason it is like this and doesn't work the same way as a CPU and memory, is because openGL was intended to run on os/system-independent hardware, so that your code can run on any OS and run on any hardware and not just the one your programming to.

Hence, because of this, you need to learn to use their preset code that makes sure that whatever you're trying to do it will be able to be run on all systems/OS/hardware within a reasonable range.

For example if you were to create your application on windows 8.1 with a certain graphics card(say amd's) you still want your application to be able to run on Andoird/iOS/Linux/other Windows systems/other hardware(gpus) such as Nvidia.

Hence why Khronos, when they created the API, they made it as system/hardware independent as possible so that it can run on everything and be a standard for everyone.

This is the price we have to pay for it, we have to learn their API instead of learning how to directly write to gpu memory and directly utilize the GPU to process information/data.

Although with the introduction of Vulkan things might be different when it is released(also from khronos)and we will find out how it will be working.